# Angular directive - scope not binded at post link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

This is how my app is structured.

```
<controller>

  <directive>

     transcluded html 

  </directive>

</controller>
```

I have a scope variable called "defaultShipTo" initiated in the controller. I am trying to access this scope variable inside the transcluded html of the directive which is inside this controller. As per rules of transcluded scope, transcluded scope is basically a copy of the parent of the directive (i.e the controller in this case).

I am trying to manipulate the transcluded html after the binding and transclusion takes place inside the directive. For this, i am using the **post-link function** within the directive.

**Directive code** -

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('checkoutApp')
    .directive('wizardCard', [wizardCardDirective]);


function wizardCardDirective(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : false,
        scope : {
           current : '@',
           checkoutStates: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'wizard-card.html',
        compile: function(element, attributes){
            console.log("compile");

             return {
                 pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){

                     console.log("pre");

                 },
                 post: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){

                    console.log("post");
                     console.log(element.html())
                 }
             }
         },

    };
}
```

})();

**template code - wizarrd-card.html -**

```
<ng-transclude></<ng-transclude>
```

**directive being used in html** -

```
<wizard-card current="shipping" checkout-states="checkoutStates">

    {{defaultShipTo}}

</wizard-card>
```

When I print out the element.html() on my console during post link, I am getting the following:

```
<ng-transclude><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    {{defaultShipTo}}
</span></ng-transclude>
```

Shouldnt I be getting "post-binded" value of defaultShipTo while in post-link?

Note: the binding does eventually happen and the value is populated, but I am not sure why it has not already happenend while in post-link.

Comment: you should use `console.log(transcludeFn();` inside the postLink function which will give you transcluded html.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Pankaj-Parkar is right, here is the working solution.
But one question here, why don't you use child directive to modify the rendered html from your template?

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('checkoutApp',[])
 .directive('wizardCard', wizardCardDirective)
 .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.defaultShipTo = 'Jon Dan';
   $scope.checkoutStates = 'inQueue';
   $scope.shipping = 'shipping Add';
 });

  function wizardCardDirective() {
 return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: false,
   scope: {
  current: '@',
  checkoutStates: '='
   },
   transclude: true,
   template: '<ng-transclude></<ng-transclude>',
   compile: function(element, attributes) {
  console.log("compile");

  return {
    pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {

   console.log("pre");

    },
    post: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {

   console.log("post");
   console.log(element.html())
   console.log(transcludeFn()[0])
    }
  }
   },

 };
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="checkoutApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
 document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <wizard-card current="shipping" checkout-states="checkoutStates">
 {{defaultShipTo}}
</wizard-card>
</body>

</html>
```